# Chrome Extension “Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive”

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, cryptojs

i try to encrypt user data by cryptojs library and send to server by ajax but the console shows the error:

Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

my manifest code contains :

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"

how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's best to remove content_security_policy and put the scripts into the extension directory and load them as any other extension script. Only then, if for some reason they won't work, use the custom csp and add cloudflare domain from the script url to the csp string.

Comment: Try adding permissions for that URL in manifest.json file.

Comment: Also Try: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",`

Answer (score 5):

For those who tumble upon the same issue. I had the same and it was resolved after I updated `content_security_policy` to include the googleapis url I was trying to load.

My code:

```html
<head>
...
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY;libraries=places"></script>
</head>
```

Needed

```json
{
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'",
}
```

Comment: worked for me without the `'unsafe-inline'`

Comment: What manifest version are you using? I think for v3 you can't use outside code.

Comment: Whats update for V3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The `script-src-elem` directive specifies valid sources for JavaScript  elements.

Try this for V3 by adding `script-src-elem`:

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com"
  }
```

Delete the  `https://maps.googleapis.com` if you don't care about it.

Some context from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy):

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy response header allows web site administrators to control resources the user agent is allowed to load for a given page. With a few exceptions, policies mostly involve specifying server origins and script endpoints. This helps guard against cross-site scripting attacks (Cross-site_scripting)
>
> ## Syntax
>
> `Content-Security-Policy: <policy-directive>; <policy-directive>`.
>
> where  consists of:   with no internal punctuation.